# How to speed up comorbidity function and trying to understand the code

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I am trying to find comorbidity score for 90K patients but its taking more number of hours after setting the parallel=T also.

I am trying understand the following line of code from comorbidity package but its giving me error.

**" Error in paste(code, id, sep = "~") : object 'code' not found "**

```
x <- data.frame(
  id = sample(1:15, size = 200, replace = TRUE),
  code = sample_diag(200),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
#the following line of code from from package and available on GitHub.
x1 <- utils::unstack(df, form = stats::as.formula(paste(code,id, sep = "~")))
```

Comment: You need to share the piece of code where the last line `x1 <- utils::unstack...` is called, so we can see what you're doing wrong. Apparently, you're not giving it the right arguments to the function `comorbidity(x = x, id = "id", code = "code", score =...` check that **code** is properly called (use of "" may be required).

Comment: I am trying to undertstand the code from here https://github.com/ellessenne/comorbidity/blob/master/R/comorbidity.R

Comment: See `?unstack` if you want to understand what line 150 of the code does. But if you want to get rid of the error, check how you're calling the `comorbidity` function. There lies the problem